# why is the table not created when I believe the script is done properly and also, what is the foreign key definition wrong? Thank you

Tags: python, sql

when I add an extra indentation at "call the main function", the database file can be created. also, the table for bookings cannot be seen when I use sqlite viewer.

new to stack overflow so I am not sure what else I must add. Please advise. Thanks!

> attached below is a screenshot of the error message I get.

```
# create database
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
conn = None
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    return conn
except Error as e:
    print(e)
return conn


# create tables
def create_table(conn, create_table_sql):
    """ create a table from the create_table_sql statement
    :param conn: Connection object
    :param create_table_sql: a CREATE TABLE statement
    :return:
    """
try:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(create_table_sql)
except Error as e:
    print(e)


def main():
    database = r"C:\Users\tommy\Desktop\CSE115 Assg 2.db"

    sql_create_customers_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
                                    CID integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                    Name text NOT NULL,
                                    Gender text NOT NULL,
                                    Mobile integer NOT NULL,
                                    Email text NOT NULL,
                                    ZipCode integer NOT NULL
                                    )"""

    sql_create_training_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS training (
                                    TID integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                    Description text NOT NULL,
                                    Duration text NOT NULL
                                    )"""

    sql_create_booking_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking (
                                    bookingid integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                    SessionDate text NOT NULL,
                                    SessionSlot text NOT NULL,
                                    FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES customers (CID),
                                    FOREIGN KEY (TID) REFERENCES training (TID)
                                    )"""

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)

    # create tables
    if conn is not None:
        # create Customers table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_customers_table)

        # create Training table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_training_table)

        # create Booking table
        create_table(conn, sql_create_booking_table)
    else:
        print("Error! cannot create the database connection.")


def create_customers(conn, customers):
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO customers(Name,Gender,Mobile,Email,ZipCode)
          VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) '''
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, customers)
    conn.commit()
    return cur.lastrowid


def create_training(conn, training):
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO training(Description,Duration)
          VALUES(?,?) '''
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, training)
    conn.commit()
    return cur.lastrowid


def create_booking(conn, booking):
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO booking(CID,TID,SessionDate,SessionSlot)
          VALUES(?,?,?,?) '''
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, booking)
    conn.commit()
    return cur.lastrowid

    with conn:
        # create 10 customers records
        customers_1 = ('Anna', 'Female', '82316375', 'anna@outlook.com', '623514')
        customers_2 = ('Benny', 'Male', '86253971', 'benny@outlook.com', '725416')
        customers_3 = ('Charles', 'Male', '92761564', 'charles@outlook.com', '536257')
        customers_4 = ('Diana', 'Female', '85243716', 'diana@outlook.com', '765987')
        customers_5 = ('Ernest', 'Male', '92761023', 'ernest@outlook.com', '625143')
        customers_6 = ('Francis', 'Male', '81237652', 'francis@outlook.com', '562712')
        customers_7 = ('Gabe', 'Male', '97165241', 'gabe@outlook.com', '832090')
        customers_8 = ('Homer', 'Male', '84256152', 'homer@outlook.com', '768451')
        customers_9 = ('Irene', 'Female', '97654112', 'irene@outlook.com', '625189')
        customers_10 = ('Joseph', 'Male', '94563421', 'joseph@outlook.com', '833164')

        create_customers(conn, customers_1)
        create_customers(conn, customers_2)
        create_customers(conn, customers_3)
        create_customers(conn, customers_4)
        create_customers(conn, customers_5)
        create_customers(conn, customers_6)
        create_customers(conn, customers_7)
        create_customers(conn, customers_8)
        create_customers(conn, customers_9)
        create_customers(conn, customers_10)

        # create 10 training records
        training_1 = ('Aerobic', '1 hour')
        training_2 = ('Aerobic', '2 hours')
        training_3 = ('Gym', '1 hour')
        training_4 = ('Gym', '2 hours')
        training_5 = ('Gym', '3 hours')
        training_6 = ('Weight Loss', '1 hour')
        training_7 = ('Weight Loss', '2 hours')
        training_8 = ('Static', '1 hour')
        training_9 = ('Static', '2 hours')
        training_10 = ('Jump', '1 hour')

        create_training(conn, training_1)
        create_training(conn, training_2)
        create_training(conn, training_3)
        create_training(conn, training_4)
        create_training(conn, training_5)
        create_training(conn, training_6)
        create_training(conn, training_7)
        create_training(conn, training_8)
        create_training(conn, training_9)
        create_training(conn, training_10)

        # create 10 booking records
        booking_1 = ('1', '1', '2021-04-02', '1')
        booking_2 = ('3', '4', '2021-04-02', '1')
        booking_3 = ('5', '4', '2021-04-02', '3')
        booking_4 = ('6', '3', '2021-04-04', '2')
        booking_5 = ('3', '4', '2021-04-06', '1')
        booking_6 = ('9', '6', '2021-04-05', '2')
        booking_7 = ('8', '10', '2021-04-05', '2')
        booking_8 = ('9', '6', '2021-04-09', '2')
        booking_9 = ('1', '2', '2021-04-09', '3')
        booking_10 = ('9', '7', '2021-04-13', '1')

        # create bookings
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_1)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_2)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_3)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_4)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_5)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_6)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_7)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_8)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_9)
        bookingid = create_booking(conn, booking_10)


# call the main function()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[This is a screenshot of the error message i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvFpr.png)

Comment: your indentations are off; your functions create_connection and create_table are not indented properly in the sample code you provided, not sure if that is an artifact of how you pasted it in here.  Also look at create_training; the return cur.lastrowid should be spaced to the right four characters. Does your original source look like that, if so, rework.

Comment: Hi thanks, I believe it is due to pasting it over here that caused an error in the indentations. I have edited the the code!

Comment: Hi, you have two instances of a 'def main' also -- I think that is confusing you especially wrt the order in which you intend to create the tables. Maybe pare down to a much smaller example.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to explain to me why there is a "unknown column 'CID' in foreign key definition?

Comment: Hi, @Tom, I see you pared it down further and that made it possible to run it without getting confused about your intent, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items have to be defined first. See this change.
The columns are now showing up in the db. I did this with Visual Studio Code, using a SQLITE Explorer extension to verify the table was being created by your code.

See also: [SQLite Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545189/sqlite-foreign-key)

```
   sql_create_booking_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS booking (
                                    bookingid integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                    SessionDate text NOT NULL,
                                    SessionSlot text NOT NULL,
                                    CID integer,
                                    TID integer,
                                    FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES customers (CID),
                                    FOREIGN KEY (TID) REFERENCES training (TID)
                                    )"""
```

Comment: I have to quit playing with this now; I can see the tables defined apparently ok but don't have the hang of viewing their contents in this extension. But I hope this will take your further.